# AndroidX could not find support-v4.aar

Tags: android, gradle, androidx

I'm trying to upgrade our app from API 25 to API 28. New gradle plugin performs redirections from old `com.android.support:support-v4:*` to `androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-alpha` , but `./gradlew build` fails to find `.aar` package for it:

```
* What went wrong:
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':rubens:noflavorDebugCompileClasspath'.
> Could not find support-v4.aar (androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0-alpha1).
  Searched in the following locations:
      https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/legacy/legacy-support-v4/1.0.0-alpha1/support-v4-1.0.0-alpha1.aar
```

This name is listed in https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/index.html , but I cannot access that package.

How can I solve that?

Answer (score 4):

The question is pretty old but I'm posting the solution I found... it might help someone in the future.

I added the following in build.gradle:

```
maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
```

[image]